# Google Analytics: filtering URI but not events sent together

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I need to filter out some URI from Google Analytics (because I send some custom pageviews on these pages instead), but not the events sent together on these pages.

The filter I applied is the following.

[image: Exclude URI filter]

Unfortunately, the filter above excludes also all the events sent on the pages included in the Filter Pattern.

How can I filter out the URI but not the events sent on those URI?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic, so I had a go at it at my blog. Maybe this works for you: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/google-analytics-filtering-uri-but-not-events-sent-together/

Answer (score 0):

The event is tracked at hit level, so filtering the hit on a page also filters the associated event. (I couldn't find a place in the documentation confirming this right now but I'm pretty confident about this).

Instead of the events, you may use [custom dimensions or metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#scope), with a session or user scope (cf. [filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#filters)). You may want to read more about scopes [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#scope), in order to identify which one works for your use case.

Also, please be aware that a [view filter is destructive](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en#limits): the filtered information will not be stored, and will never be available in the future. Based on your use case, you may want to take one of these approaches instead:

- use segments or filters inside reports instead of view filters.
- create an additional view, not containing any filter, so that full dataset is available whenever needed

Comment: Or he could pass in a hit scoped custom dimension to the pageview but not the event and filter by that.

Comment: @EikePierstorff are you sure? In link "filters" above, one can read: "Both Custom dimensions with hit scope and custom metrics will be filtered if the hit they are associated with was also filtered"

Comment: Pretty sure, since the event is a hit on its own, not something added to a pageview. But I'll test later this evening to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're using the Filter to remove hits. This means that any hits that match the filter will be lost, including Event and Page View hits.

It sounds like what you require is some kind of search and replace that strips out those custom URIs from the hits that they accompany: so the hits go ahead, but the custom URIs are edited out of them.

Alternatively, you could alter the reporting on those events so that they tell Google Analytics that they take place on a different page.